# dynamodb node js --- UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

i have an app connected to a local dynamodb, written in typescript on yop of node js (express) using the aws-sdk.
i am trying to connect to the locally running dynamo, and getting that error when trying to perform different operations (list table, delete table etc):

UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.

cant resolve that, been trying for a whole day, configured local credentials for the aws console etc.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share a piece of code where you initiate a DDB client instance?

Comment: I think it's either the credentials are wrong, the region used is wrong or the credentials are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's either the credentials are wrong, the region used is wrong or the credentials are invalid.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Comment: It is 3 answers to a question that can have 3 possibles. What was your answer?

Comment: No, it's not an answer. You can check [answer]. For a good answer, you should explain why it can be one of them, how to know which is of them, how to fix etc

Comment: I dont see why you need a step-by-step guide to updating your credentials file.